# Unable to use pre - launch task more than once in VS Code

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, bgi

I'm trying to use pre-launch task more than once to execute two different tasks in my launch.json file. Unfortunately, it only executes the last pre-launch task in my launch.json file. The tasks that are in my tasks.json use the same command("g++") to compile my program, but their arguments are different (that's because I need to compile my source code first into an "O" file then compile the "O" file into an "exe" file), so I'm finding a way on how can I execute those two tasks in the launch.json file using one pre-launch task only. Any other ideas please?

tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "CompileToOfile",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-c","${fileBasename}",
                "-o","${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o",
                "-I","/Users/Acer/MinGW64/include",
                "-I","/Users/Acer/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
                "-I","/Users/Acer/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include",
                "-I","/Users/Acer/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++",
                "-m32"
            ],
            "isShellCommand": true
        },
        {
            "taskName": "CompileWGDBWBGI",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-L","/Users/Acer/MinGW64/lib32",
                "-L","Users/Acer/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32",
                "-static-libgcc",
                "-lbgi",
                "-lgdi32",
                "-lcomdlg32",
                "-luuid",
                "-loleaut32",
                "-lole32",
                "-m32"
            ],
            "isShellCommand": true
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Launch",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "CompileToOfile",
            "preLaunchTask": "CompileWGDBWBGI",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "CompileToOfile",
            "preLaunchTask": "CompileWGDBWBGI",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/Users/Acer/MinGW64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one `preLaunchTask`, but you could add `"dependsOn": "CompileToOfile"` to your `CompileWGDBWBGI` task and then use that as your `preLaunchTask`. This way, `CompileToOfile` is executed before each execution of `CompileWGDBWBGI`.

Comment: When I hover the cursor over the word "dependsOn" it says "Property dependsOn is not allowed" which is why I think it won't execute the CompileWGDBWBGI task. Do I need to do something else before I use "dependsOn" or is it that there is a specified location for the "dependsOn",(P.S. I placed it after the "taskName")

Comment: You need to use Tasks version 2.0.0 (I just saw you have 0.1.0 in your `tasks.json`).

Comment: When I posted my answer, I first tested it with this minimal `tasks.json` setup: https://pastebin.com/2GrKPmDY - that appears to work as expected?

Comment: So now my problem is that how can I prevent the terminal from being focused when I start debugging, I was forced to remove the "isShellCommand" because v2.0.0 doesn't support it.

Comment: Try `"reveal": "never"` in the `presentation` structure (if you're on VSCode 1.14.0, this changed a bit in that release).